# How to group in a list matching strings from elements from other string lists in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got 744 image files with names with the following scheme: 'mission_code_coord_date1_date2_01_T1/2_Bnumber.TIF'. Like in this list, for example:

```
files = [
'LM02_L1TP_028046_19760327_20180424_01_T2_B6.TIF', #--¬
'LM02_L1TP_028047_19760327_20180424_01_T2_B6.TIF', #---note match except in the 'coord' part
'LT05_L1TP_026046_19951010_20170106_01_T1_B5.TIF',
'LT05_L1TP_026047_19951010_20170107_01_T1_B5.TIF',
'LC08_L1TP_026047_20150713_20170226_01_T1_B1.TIF']
#---------^-----^
#         9    15
```

The objective is to group the files in sublists for those whose 'mission_code' and 'date1_date2_01_T1/2_Bnumber.TIF' matches, then the output would be an array like this:

```
ord_files=[
    ['LM02_L1TP_028046_19760327_20180424_01_T2_B6.TIF','LM02_L1TP_028047_19760327_20180424_01_T2_B6.TIF'],
    ['LT05_L1TP_026046_19951010_20170106_01_T1_B5.TIF','LT05_L1TP_026047_19951010_20170107_01_T1_B5.TIF'],
    ['LC08_L1TP_026047_20150713_20170226_01_T1_B1.TIF','']]
```

Some files have a pair, triplet or they are alone.
My idea was remove the string from the *coord* part in a new list, mo_files, so that could be easy to do a filter and then with a conditional create the otput list, ord_files.

On that mood so far I have tried things like:

```
for k in range(len(files)):
    mo_files[k][:] = files[k][9] + files[k][15]
```

Only im getting errors like `IndexError: list index out of range`
There is a simpler or better method?.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess the `mo_files[k]` is your index error. You might want to use `mo_files.append()`. Unrelated, instead of complicated one-liners, I suggest writing slowly. For instance, implement the function `get_mission` that receives a name of an image file and returns the name of the mission.

Comment: your expected output is wrong since in your second list date2 is `20170106` and `20170107`

Comment: @kederrac True!, didnt notice first time, but fixed adding ` and i != 4` . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
d = {} # you can also use collections.defaultdict

for f in files:
    d.setdefault(tuple(e for i, e in enumerate(f.split('_')) if i != 2), []).append(f)
list(d.values())
```

output:

```
[['LM02_L1TP_028046_19760327_20180424_01_T2_B6.TIF',
  'LM02_L1TP_028047_19760327_20180424_01_T2_B6.TIF'],
 ['LT05_L1TP_026046_19951010_20170106_01_T1_B5.TIF'],
 ['LT05_L1TP_026047_19951010_20170107_01_T1_B5.TIF'],
 ['LC08_L1TP_026047_20150713_20170226_01_T1_B1.TIF']]
```

---

or  you  can use:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list) 
for f in files:
    d[tuple(e for i, e in enumerate(f.split('_')) if i != 2)].append(f)

list(d.values())
```

this version is a bot faster

Comment: Elegant answer. I think author would like to group by  `mission_code` **and** `date1_date2_01_T1/2_Bnumber.TIF`. Hence `f.split('_', 1)[0]` doesn't seems like the right key, but `"_".join([part for idx, part in enumerate(filename.split("_")) if idx != 2])` would. What do you think?

Comment: @Arnaud thx I've updated my answer and I use `tuple(e for i, e in enumerate(f.split('_')) if i != 2)`

Comment: From my understanding, the key is **all** except the 2nd element given by the `split`

Answer (score 1):

If you're into `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(files, columns=["filename"])                                                                                                                                 

# indeed define a "key" that is the whole string without 'coord' part
df["key"] = df.filename.apply(lambda s: s[:9]+s[16:])
```

Now all you have to do is `groupby` and aggregate using `list`:

```
>>> df.groupby("key").filename.apply(list).values                                                                                                                                  
array([list(['LC08_L1TP_026047_20150713_20170226_01_T1_B1.TIF']),
       list(['LM02_L1TP_028046_19760327_20180424_01_T2_B6.TIF', 'LM02_L1TP_028047_19760327_20180424_01_T2_B6.TIF']),
       list(['LT05_L1TP_026046_19951010_20170106_01_T1_B5.TIF']),
       list(['LT05_L1TP_026047_19951010_20170107_01_T1_B5.TIF'])],
      dtype=object)
```

By the way, if you're not sure whether indices could change within the 700+ files, then a more stable solution is to make things using `_`-splitting:

```
df["key"] = df.filename.apply(
    lambda filename: "_".join([part for idx, part in enumerate(filename.split("_")) if idx != 2])
)
```